# How ist the DataContext of a Unsercontrol related to its DependencyProperties?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, datacontext

while working with UserControls having DependencyProperties i realized that it is curcial to consider where to set the DataContext. To picture it ive created a sample application. There are two UserControls, both equal except on where the DataContext is set:

Working UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DpropTest.OkUserControl"
         ...>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=dpropTest:OkUserControl }}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyDepProp}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Not working user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DpropTest.NotOkUserControl"
         ...
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=dpropTest:NotOkUserControl}}" 
         >
<Grid >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyDepProp}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Both UserControls have a DependencyProperty called MyDepProp,

```
 #region Dependency Property Declaration
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDepPropProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyDepProp", typeof(string), typeof(NotOkUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string MyDepProp
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyDepPropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyDepPropProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion Dependency Property Declaration
```

This is how i integrated the UserControls to the mainWindow:

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">
    <StackPanel>
        <dpropTest:OkUserControl MyDepProp="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ParentGrid}"/>
        <dpropTest:NotOkUserControl MyDepProp="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ParentGrid}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The running application shows the actualWith for the first UserControlonly only, the second UserControl remains unset as the DP doesnt bind.

There is no error in the output window regarding the second UserControl...

Maybe there is an WPF Pro out there with an brief explanation? 
Thank you! 
Uli

Answer (score 1):

I don't think FindAncestor will start with the element itself, but apart from that: you can either set this on the UserControl:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

or set this in the constructor of the user control, before the InitializeComponent:

```
DataContext = this;
```

As a sidenote: it's often not necessary to bind with the ActualWidth of some ancestor; in this case the width of the stackpanel is the same as the width of its parent grid and the width of the usercontrols is the same as the width of ths stackpanel. So in effect MyDepProp is equal to the ActualWidth of the usercontrol.

Comment: actually it isnt about ActualWith, ive just dragged that property for a quick sample. I dont get why it is apparently so much of a differernce wheather the dataContext is declared on the <UserControl > or on a contained FrameworkElement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<UserControl x:Class="DpropTest.NotOkUserControl"
         ...
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=dpropTest:OkUserControl }}"
```

Seems to me you are binding to wrong parent! You are inside NotOkUserControl but you are asking for unreachable AncestorType...

Comment: NotOkUserControl would still not be its own ancester.

Comment: Actually is this the source of my confusion. The only difference between the to UserControls is that for the working one the DataContext ist set at LayoutRoot: <Grid DataContext...> where as for the not working on right at the class <UserControl...DataContext=...>

Comment: Read again what I wrote to you. You are binding to wrong parent that is why you have no DataContext. Seeking for AncestorType = OKUserControl in header of NotOkUserControl does not make any sense. Consider changing your binding definition. The position where you define your relative binding in VisualTree also matters

Comment: Hi, sorry, ive misstype it, ive changed  the binding to the right type NotOkUserControl the beaviour is unchanged. Is it possible to load up source files? Thanks!

Comment: I think you misunderstood me :) I was saying that your binding is completely wrong in general no matter what AncestorType you pick. {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} might fix your problem. At least you will have DataContext then